# Airflow connection created without password and connection type

Tags: python-3.x, airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a Snowflake connection in Airflow programmatically using DAG. However, after running the DAG file in Airflow, the connection is created without password and connection type. Please advise. The python code is as below:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
    'email': ['me@me.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG(
    'MakeConnection',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Test',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
)

def BuildConnection():

    conn = Connection(
            conn_id='SNOWFLAKECONNECTION',
            conn_type='Snowflake'
            host='abc.snowflakecomputing.com',
            login='AIRFLOW',
            password='123',
            schema='PUBLIC',
            port=443,
            extra=json.dumps(dict(Account='abc')),
            )
    session = settings.Session() # get the session
    session.add(conn)
    session.commit()

run_Rule_SOW = PythonOperator(
    task_id='BuildConnection',
    python_callable=BuildConnection,
    dag=dag,
    )
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Why are you creating the connection inside the dag itself? Connections in airflow are normally handled in Hooks and not in the DAG definition.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is using the Snowflake Python connector, I think you might have the wrong parameter for `login`.  Should be `user`.  Its hard to tell from your post what it is that you are seeing, though.  Are you getting an error message that you could share?

Comment: There is no error. After running the DAG, a connection has been created in Airflow. However, Conn Type and Password fields are empty in the connection although I have put values in the python code. Is there any way, I can attach the image of the AirFlow connection screen here?